# Change IP of PHP PDO MySQL connection based on network

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, vagrant

I just setup an environment via Vagrant for consistency across 2 development laptops. I am using a remote MySQL server (home server) with PHP PDO. I wanted to know if I can use PHP to determine if I am on the local network as the MySQL server and connect to it via 192.168.1.111 or if I am not on the same network as the MySQL server and connect to it through ***.dyndns.org.

I have the local and remote connections setup correctly and they are both working.

How can I use PHP to connect to the MySQL server locally if it is available, but if not via the remote address?

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_IP . ';port=' . DB_PORT . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Can't you just build up the connection for your local, and if you get an error code back you connect to the remote one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you just try something like this?!:

```
$opt = array(
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

try
{
   $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
   $dsn = "mysql:host=yourRemoteHost;dbname=testRemoteHost;charset=utf8";
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
}
```

Like this you try to connect to localhost and if it does not work, you catch the exception and connect to the remote. Just use your data for mysql:host etc.

Christian Gollhardt mentioned that you could probably use the "`Throw new Exception...`" way if you are in dev state. But that shouldn't be an Exception anymore if you are in product environment - you will have to rebuild this part of code anyways then.

Comment: Excepetions should not occour unitl it is realy a exception.

Comment: Well, just use an echo then but catch the Exception

Comment: Okay i thought about my comment. You have a good point. If you're in dev state, wo could call this a exception. +1 (But i would point this out in the answer)

Comment: `if you are in product environment` - code like that shouldn't exist in a product *ion* environment.

Comment: Yea thats true, he has to rebuild that when hes in product environment - But I think thats clear. I just wanted to point out that he has to think about when to use an Exception.